# Getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my program below on running it I'm getting an error `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException`.
In this program, I am trying to test a login page with 4 different sets of data using `DataProvider` annotation so my script is running

1. Chrome gets initiated
2. website gets open
3. click and enter username and password

And the above three steps happen for each set of data provided.
But still on the completion of the whole thing, I'm getting this error. Please help!

````
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import basePage.*;

//Login to edureka website


public class myPorfileupdate 
{
    
    WebDriver driver1;
  
   
   @Test (dataProvider ="edulogin")
    public void myLogin(String username, String password) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {  AppTest a =new AppTest();
       driver1 = a.initializeDriver();
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-button-name='Login']")).click();
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).clear();
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys(username);
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"new_sign_up_optim\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/form/button")).click();
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         try{ 
                
                WebElement d= driver1.findElement(By.linkText("Trending Courses"));
                System.out.println(d);
            }    
            catch (Exception Ex){ 
                // Get text displayes on login page 
                System.out.println("Userid/password is incorrect");
            } 
                
            }
   
    
    
    
    @DataProvider(name="edulogin")
    
        public Object[][] testData() {

            Object[][] data = new Object[4][2];
            data[0][0] = "ambika97.singh@gmail.com";
            data[0][1] = "Omsairam@1234";
            //2nd row
            data[1][0] = "abc";
            data[1][1] = "Omsairam@1234";
            //3rd row
            data[2][0] = "ambika97.singh@gmail.com";
            data[2][1] = "xyz";
            //4th row
            data[3][0] = "abc";
            data[3][1] = "xyz";
            return data;
}
  
   
   

}```



**First two lines of my console are**
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.
````

Comment: what code line gives the exception?

Comment: Thankyou for your response! I resolved it my xpath for password field was incorrect for some reason and hence it was giving me org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException error.